# Cambiar un valor de la configuración en Laravel

Tags: laravel, idioma, configuración

Tengo una ruta con una función para cambiar el valor de app.locale, que puede ser inglés o español, así:

```
Route:: get('/change-language/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    config(['app.locale' => $locale]);
    return redirect()->route('index');
})->name('ch-lg');
```

le he hecho un `dd(config('app.locale'));` en el interior de la función, y sí, me lo cambia. El problema es que cuando vuelvo a index no coge ese valor del que he cambiado con la función, sino del que existe en el fichero `config/app.php`. Por lo tanto, no puedo cambiar el idioma en la ejecución.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que mantenga el valor que le doy durante el resto de ejecución de la aplicación?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuve un problema similar a ese. Tenía en el enrutador una ruta parecida a la tuya. Lo que hice fue recibir el valor del idioma elegido y guardarlo en una variable de sesión. Por poner los mismos nombres que tú, para que lo veas claro, lo hice así:

```
Route:: get('/change-language/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    session(['locale' => $locale]);
    return back();
})->name('ch-lg');
```

Luego me creé un middleware al que llamé Languages, con Artisan, así: `php artisan make:middleware Languages`. Su código lo puse así:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class Languages
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        App::setLocale(session('locale'));
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Después lo referencié en `app/Http/Kernel.php`, en la matriz `$middlewareGroups`, bajo la clave `web`, así:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Languages::class,
    ],
```

Y apañado. Todos los controladores que se llamen desde rutas que estén en `web.php` van a usar ese middleware, y a mí me funcionó. Pruébalo.

Comment: Guauuuu. Funciona perfecto. Gracias. Por qué no pondrán estas cosas en la documentación?

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza el método `setLocale()` en el facade `App` para que se mantenga en la sesión:

```
Route::get('change-language/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    App::setLocale($locale);

    //
});
```

---

Por si acaso, para obtener este valor, no lo lees de la configuración, de nuevo, usas un método del facade App:

```
$locale = App::getLocale();
```

Todo lo encuentras en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/localization

Comment: Lo he probado y tampoco funciona. Sigue manteniendo el valor `en` que tiene en `config/app.php` en lugar del `es` que le paso en la llamada. A la función llega bien, así que la llamada es correcta, pero luego lo pierde y se va al valor que hay grabado. Y también he probado a limpiar la cache con `php artisan cache:clear`, y tampoco funciona.

Comment: Además, he probado a poner el cambio en un método del controlador. Siempre ocurre lo mismo. Coge bien el valor que le paso, lo graba, pero luego, al cambiar a otro método, lo pierde y coge el valor por defecto.

Comment: A mí me funciona bien en varios proyectos multilingües que tengo (con hasta 5 idiomas distintos), sin ningún inconveniente. ¿Los demás datos en la sesión funcionan bien?

Comment: Revisa la edición que hice, para obtener el valor del locale no utilizas el helper config, utilizas la función que indica la documentación en el enlace que te di.

Comment: Nada, que no me funciona. Y he probado a crear una variable de sesión cuando hago el cambio, y esa si la mantiene al pasar a otro método, pero el idioma lo pierde, recogiendo el que hay en `config/app.php`. La documentación me la he mirado de arriba abajo (ya la había mirado antes de preguntar), pero no encuentro nada que no haya probado ya. Y el caso es que, antes del cambio a otro método del controlador, mantiene el valor pasado. Es en el cambio, donde lo pierde.

Comment: Además, si fuerzo en el controlador el idioma español, da lo mismo. Al pasar a la vista me coge las cadenas del fichero en inglés. He probado a poner en el controlador `App::setLocale('es')`, le hago un `dump(App:getLocale());` y me muestra `es`, pero cuando cuando llega a la vista coge las variables del inglés, no del español. Ya no sé por donde cogerlo.